# How to connect dots in ggplot - 2 separate geom_point functions

Tags: r, ggplot2

Creating a Cleveland dot plot, that looks like this.....[image: dot plot]

Here's a bit of the data frame:

```
  statement_code avg_score statement_title           domain  benchmark_score
1      Q.DMM1_01  1.596218 We have the right...      Culture 2.09
2      Q.DMM1_02  1.597330 We invest in targeted...  Culture 2.25
3      Q.DMM1_03  1.398220 We prioritize overall...  Culture 2.16
4      Q.DMM1_04  2.106785 Our board and our...      Culture 2.13
```

And here's the code I used.....

```
Culture <- subset(DMM_summary, domain=="Culture")
ggplot(Culture, aes(x=1,y=statement_title)) + 
geom_point(aes(x=benchmark_score), shape=19,color="grey55",size=6) +
geom_point(aes(x=avg_score),shape=19,color="forestgreen",size=6) +
geom_path() +  
geom_text(aes(x=benchmark_score, y=statement_title, label = format(round(benchmark_score, 1),nsmall=1)),colour="grey60",size=4, hjust=-0.8) +
geom_text(aes(x=avg_score,y=statement_title, label = format(round(avg_score, 1),nsmall=1)),colour="forestgreen",size=4, hjust=2) +
scale_x_continuous(name="Average score - scale of 0 [completely disagree] to 3 [completely agree]",limits=c(0,3)) + 
ylab("") +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey65", face="bold", size=10),
      axis.title.x = element_text(colour="grey45", face="italic", size=10),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill="white"),
      panel.grid.major.x=element_line(colour="grey85", linetype="dashed"),
      panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour="grey85", linetype="dashed"))
```

What I want to do is connect the green dots vertically, and the grey dots vertically (e.g. from 1.5 to 1.4 to 1.6 to 1.6 to 1.5 to 2.2 to 2.1 in green). I've tried geom_line() with no joy.

Comment: See [ggalt package](https://rud.is/b/2016/04/12/beating-lollipops-into-dumbbells/), they are also called "dumbbell plot".

Comment: Can't give specific help without data but you could reshape the dataframe (long format, e.g. `tidyr::gather`) and then you would need only one `geom_point` and one `geom_text`. Then you could plot `geom_path(aes(group = statement_title))`

Comment: That seems to give me horizontal lines, not vertical joins which is what I need.

Comment: need some data to help

Comment: data now added, so original post (edited)